# Combinatorics for bit string.

Tags: combinatorics

How many different bit strings can be transmitted if the string must begin with a 1 bit, must include three additional 1 (so that a total of four 1 bits is sent), must include a total of 12 0 bits, and must have at least two 0 bits following each 1 bit ?

There are a total of 16 bits but we only need to worry about the last 13 since the first bit must be a 1 and followed by two zeros as such:

```
1 0 0 _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _  _ _ _ _  _
```

There are 3 more 1 bits followed by two zeros we must consider and the possible combinations are:

```
1 0 0      1 0 0    1 0 0    1 0 0    0 0 0 0
1 0 0      1 0 0    1 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0 0
1 0 0      1 0 0    1 0 0    0 0 1    0 0 0 0
1 0 0      1 0 0    1 0 0    0 0 0    1 0 0 0
.....
.....
.....
```

and so on...

Since there are 13 bits to consider and 9 of those spots need to be arranged in the manner of a 1 bit followed by two 0 bits would the total possible number of combinations be `C(13,9)` ?

Comment: Hint: you can consider the sequence 1-0-0 as a single symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $3$ elements of the form $100$ and $4$ zeros to place in $13$ positions as you say (we ignore the first three because they are indeed fixed). So, by considering the element $100$ as a unity, you actually have $3$ (compounded) elements  and $4$ zeros to place in $7$ positions. For example $$x \, 0 \, x \, 0 \,x \, 0 \, 0$$ stands for $$100\,0\,100\,0\,100\,0\,0$$You can do it in $$\dbinom{7}{3}=\frac{7!}{3!4!}=35$$ ways.